# Selective Child Transforms in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, transformation

I'm wondering if it's possible to selectively apply parent transforms to a child node within javafx.

To my understanding when a node is tranformed all the children of said node are also transformed.

My question is: Is it possible to disable types of parent transforms within the child so that when the parent is tranformed only a select type of transforms are passed.

Similar to this:
[image]

I would like to rotate the group node without rotating the text but I would like the text position to be effected by the rotation.

Hopefully i've explained myself.

---

Currently I simply apply the opposite rotation to the text when the group is transformed but it's getting to the point where expanding my scene graph is making this more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no: the transforms of the group are always propagated to all its children.

However, I think here you just want the rotate property of the text to be the negative of the rotate property of the group:

```
text.rotateProperty().bind(group.rotateProperty().multiply(-1));
```

Since the `rotateProperty` defines a rotation about the center of the node, when the group is rotated, it (and all its child nodes) will be rotated about its center, then the binding ensures the text is rotated about its center in the opposite direction.

If you want something more general, it gets a bit tricky. One possible approach is to observe the `localToSceneTransform` of the parent of the text you want to keep horizontal. That property represents the cumulative transform that maps coordinates in the parent to coordinates in the scene. Then you can take a horizontal line in the local coordinate space in the parent, transform it to the scene, and look at the angle it creates. You then want to rotate the text by the negative of this angle.

Here's a demo:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RotateGroupKeepTextAligned extends Application {   

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        StackPane container = new StackPane();
        Group outer = new Group();
        Rectangle outerRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 400);
        outerRect.setFill(Color.ANTIQUEWHITE);
        outer.getChildren().add(outerRect);

        Text outerText = new Text(5,  5, "Outer Group");
        Group inner = new Group();
        inner.relocate(10, 25);
        Text innerText = new Text(5, 5, "Inner Group");
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50, 150, 150);
        rect.setFill(Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE);
        Text fixedAlignmentText = new Text(100, 220, "Horizontal Text");

        inner.localToSceneTransformProperty().addListener((obs, oldT, newT) -> {
            // figure overall rotation angle of inner:
            Point2D leftScene = newT.transform(new Point2D(0, 0));
            Point2D rightScene = newT.transform(new Point2D(1, 0));

            double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(rightScene.getY() - leftScene.getY(), rightScene.getX() - leftScene.getX()));

            fixedAlignmentText.setRotate(-angle);
        });

        outer.setStyle("-fx-background-color: antiquewhite;");
        outer.getChildren().addAll(outerText, inner);

        inner.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
        inner.getChildren().addAll(innerText, rect, fixedAlignmentText);

        container.getChildren().add(outer);
        root.setCenter(container);

        VBox controls = new VBox(5,
                makeControls("Outer Group", outer),
                makeControls("Inner Group", inner));

        root.setBottom(controls);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Node makeControls(String title, Node node) {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();

        Label label = new Label(title);
        Spinner<Double> rotateSpinner = new Spinner<>(0, 360, 0, 5);
        node.rotateProperty().bind(rotateSpinner.getValueFactory().valueProperty());
        rotateSpinner.getValueFactory().setWrapAround(true);

        Button up = createTranslateButton(node, Node::translateYProperty, -2, "^");
        Button down = createTranslateButton(node, Node::translateYProperty, 2, "v");
        Button left = createTranslateButton(node, Node::translateXProperty, -2, "<");
        Button right = createTranslateButton(node, Node::translateXProperty, 2, ">");

        grid.add(label, 0, 0, 3, 1);
        grid.add(new Label("Rotation:"), 0, 1, 1 ,2);
        grid.add(rotateSpinner, 1, 1, 1, 2);
        grid.add(up, 3, 1);
        grid.add(down, 3, 2);
        grid.add(left, 2, 1, 1, 2);
        grid.add(right, 4, 1, 1, 2);

        grid.setHgap(5);
        grid.setVgap(5);

        return grid ;
    }

    private Button createTranslateButton(Node node, Function<Node, DoubleProperty> property, double delta, String text) {
        Button button = new Button(text);
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            DoubleProperty prop = property.apply(node);
            prop.set(prop.get() + delta);
        });
        return button ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this work even if the rotation is applied to the root of the group?

Comment: No, in that case you would need `text.rotateProperty().bind(root.rotateProperrty()...);` To generalize would be difficult, just to define exact what you mean from a geometric standpoint.

Comment: Ah thank you. It's looking like the problem is much larger than I thought.
I'm simply trying to have the text within my scene graph not rotate while everything else within the scene graph does. Now as my scene graph is getting larger i'm trying to generalise but it's looking like i'll just have to declare each text node.

Comment: @jogden16761 See update for ideas for a more general approach.

Comment: I actually fixed the problem in a bit of a messy way but it "works". I  created a custom class to hold any text I created "TextClass". I would then recursively scan through the scene graph (horrible i know) and if a "TextClass" was detected I would apply an inverse rotation. this would only work with a predetermined rotation object but it'll do for the project I'm working on. On that note, i'm guna read through the code and see if your idea is better.

Comment: This look pretty perfect. Never thought you could apply listeners in this way. Thanks a bunch, i'll try implementing now, you've saved me a lot of technical debt by the looks of things.

Comment: If you want a standalone class to implement this, it's pretty easy to refactor that way...